# Example of binary operators in C++?

Tags: c++, binary-operators

I am currently  a beginner in C++ and learning about operators.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned int a=195;
    unsigned int b=87;
    unsigned int c;
    c=a&b;
    cout << c;
}
```

The Output of the above program is : 67

[This is explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pxxg.gif)

But What is the practical use of this?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a boolean operator. It is a **binary** AND operator. The practical use of this comes from Boolean algebra, which should be studied before any programming attempt is made.

Comment: Oops, I mean Binary.

Comment: Correct it....., Thanks